# disable eventClick to google events

Tags: javascript, events, click, fullcalendar

Reading through the documentation on FullCalendar, I thought I could find a way to disable clicking an event, leading the browser to the original Google Calendar. But for unknown reasons the script I use does not disable the browser to open a new window.

I am quite new to script, so I may have easily made a mistake.
This is what I tried to use but does not function, yet...

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here
    weekNumbers: 'true',
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: '',
        right: 'today,prev,next,',
    },
    editable: 'true',
    eventSources: [
        {url: 'https://www.google.com/ca...',
        className: 'tehuur',
        },
            {url: 'https://www.google.com/cale...',
        className: 'verhuurd',
        },
    ],
    eventClick: function(event) {
        if (event.url) {
            window.open(event.url);
            return false;
        }
    }
})
```

});

Can anybody point me in the right direction to disable the eventClick. Thanks for your help.

Ben

Comment: Have you read the code you posted? It says eventClick right there which opens a new window etc...

Comment: Yes, that is why i am surprised that it still leads me to a google calendar page upon clicking an event. 

I would like to disable this. I was told, implementing the codepart which states "return false" would NOT open a new Google page.

However this does not seem to work.

Maybe someone please help me in disabling this eventclicking with a different code or show me what I did wrong in the code above.
Help is appreciated....

Comment: Are you actually asking how to redirect instead of opening a new window? it's hard to tell

Answer (score 1):

```
eventClick: function(event) {
  if (event.url) {
    if (event.url.includes('google.com')){
      return false;
    }
    console.log(event.url.includes('google.com'));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the eventClick function. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pba56nf1/5/)

This line was opening a new window to google calendar: `window.open(event.url);`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        weekNumbers: 'true',
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: '',
            right: 'today,prev,next,',
        },
        editable: true,
        events: 'http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic',
        eventClick: function() {
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

**Edit:**

If you want to redirect instead of opening a new window you should use:
`window.location.href = event.url;`
instead of `window.open(event.url)`.

Comment: Thanks Richard, for trying to solve my problem. As your code shows in the Fiddle, the agenda items are still clickable and when clicked, lead away (opening a new window) while and although the code is still unchanged. My preference would be that any item showing in the agenda, only shows without being a clickable link. But apparently this cannot be achieved. In a sense a redirect would be helpful, if the new direction would lead nowhere in stead of back to the Google Calendar.

Comment: Events are clickable but they don't lead away to anywhere. I think this question probably qualifies under minimum understanding or something. The page seems to refresh though so I added the return false on the function.

Comment: @BenvanWetten Is clicking an event still opening a new window? If so, what browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, clicking an event still opens a new window.

In this window the clicked Google event is displayed from the public google calendar that is used as the eventsource. 
(when logged in on the google account, the event shows as is editable, logged out it shows the simple data of the event)

Comment: When I use a different form of eventsources, (like an array in the respective  page-script) the events are, as you mention, clickable as well, but the do not open a new window (there is no action after the click).

I have inserted the FullCalendar script in a HTML5 -  bootstrap 2.2.2 based website setup. 
And it works beautiful, except for my wish to change the action on clicking an event from eventSource google calendar.

Comment: Browsers used for checking this eventclick:
Google Chrome version 38
Firefox 33.0 (yes, installed this morning...)

I am quite new to javascript, I must admit, but know my way around most of the other areas needed here.
kind regards, Ben